# use sockets with ionic2

Tags: node.js, ionic2

I need to be able to use udp or tcp sockets on an ionic2 app. I tried using the 'dgram' module that comes with node.js, I can import it  but as soon as I try to use it in my class and do ionic serve I see these errors:
Example: 
This line alone in my class is fine after "ionic serve"

`import dgram  from 'dgram';`

but as soon as I try to use use, like:

`let server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');`

and run "ionic serve" I see these errors on the browser:

`Cannot find module "dgram`

```
Error: Cannot find module "dgram"
at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:60926:79)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:60926:161)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:103698:14)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92433:23)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:118153:20)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18
```

After some googling it seems that I can not proceed that way because that is considered 'server-side' code.

Has anybody been able to add that sort of functionality on an ionic2 app?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What library are you trying to use?

Comment: UDP / Datagram Sockets from node.js: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/dgram.html